# define a constant constraint by a percentage of the views height

Tags: swift, constants, constraints, percentage, nslayoutconstraint

In my swift code below I am trying to constraint the pic to 10 percent below the top anchor at all times. To do that by a constant [image]. Like the picture below the orange box is constraint 10 percent below the top anchor and its a constant. I tried messing around with the constant in the constraints its not working.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var drawView = UIView()
        var pic = UIImageView()


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

            
            [pic,drawView].forEach{
                $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                view.addSubview($0)
            }
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
     //here is the constant
                pic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,constant,),
                pic.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                pic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.25),
                pic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.8),
                
                drawView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                drawView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                drawView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.3),
                drawView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.9),
                
              
                

                
                
            ])
            view.bringSubviewToFront(pic)
            drawView.backgroundColor = .blue
            pic.backgroundColor = .purple
         
        }


        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an invisible view whose height is 1/10 the height of the superview, by way of its multiplier, to act as a spacer. Now just make its bottom the top of the visible view.